# Upgraded Ubuntu, can't connect to MySQL server

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

When I try to connect to MySQL, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

It seems like this is a common error as I googled it and found a lot of responses. I tried a lot of the responses to fix it and here are the various error messages I receive:

When running service mysql start:

```
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.10" (uid=1002 pid=5788 comm="start) interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply=0 destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init"))
```

When running mysqld -P 3305:

```
101115 11:06:02 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/ubuntu.lower-test
101115 11:06:02 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/ubuntu.lower-test
101115 11:06:02 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
101115 11:06:02 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
101115 11:06:02  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

When running ps -ef | grep mysql:

```
victor    5809  5688  0 11:08 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

I've tried purging MySQL and reinstalling it but I get the same errors every time.

Everything was working fine but I upgraded the Ubuntu Server software and things don't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

cp /etc/mysql/my.cnf.dpkg-dist /etc/mysql/my.cnf

invoke-rc.d mysql start

Answer (score 0):

Check your MySQL datadir permission.